# How to implement Master details classes find function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, class

I have this code:

```
function Item(id, itemType, itemData, itemCategoryId, itemRank) {
    this.id = id;
    this.itemType = itemType;
    this.itemData = itemData;
    this.itemCategoryId = itemCategoryId;
    this.itemRank = itemRank;
}
function Category(id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

And I want to write a function for the `Item` class which I give it the `CategoryId` and it will return all items objects with this Category id.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no array....

I would assume that there would be an items prototype (*[note that there are no classes in javascript](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2008/10/Journal200810.jsp#a1)*), and it would look something like this:

```
function Item(id, categoryId, data, rank) {
  this.id = id;
  this.categoryId = categoryId;
  this.data = data;
  this.rank = rank;
}

function Items() {
  this.items = [];
  this.findByCategory = function(categoryId) { 
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0;i<this.items.length;i++) {
       if (categoryId == this.items[i].categoryId) 
          result.push(this.items[i]);
    }
    return result;
  }
  this.add = function(id, categoryId, data, rank) {
    this.items.push(new Item(id, categoryId, data, rank));  
  }
}

var items = new Items();
items.add(2, 0, null, null); 
items.add(1, 1, null, null); // I'm not going to care about data and rank here
items.add(2, 1, null, null); 
items.add(3, 1, null, null); 
items.add(4, 2, null, null); 
items.add(5, 3, null, null); 

var cat1 = items.findByCategory(1);
alert(cat1); // you will get a result of 3 objects all of which have category 1
```